# sqlite3 concurrent writes

Tags: concurrency, sqlite

I get a table which contains 100 lines of datas. (Sqlite3 and Linux)

Each on these lines are updated by several processes.
Since a same line cannot be modified twice (a process "owned" a line and only one), do you think I really need to use transactions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite does not have concurrent writes.
As long as one process is writing to a database file, other processes that want to write have to wait.

SQLite *always* uses transactions.
If you don't explicitly execute `BEGIN`/`COMMIT` commands, every single command will be automatically wrapped in a transaction.

So your program should work fine as is.